# How to utilize the unused memory(total memory in machine is 4GB RAM) left by host OS Win XP in my virtual machine

Tags: memory, virtual-machine

I have a host machine with 4 GB RAM and Win XP Pro 32 bit.Now my host machine is using approximately 1.5 GB of RAM and at max it can use 3.25 GB (approx) RAM. SO I have around 0.75 GB (approx) RAM left unused. I am creating a virtual machine with VMware Player 5.0 for windows 8 32 bit. Can I allocate 2.5 GB RAM to this virtual machine? I am wondering if my virtual machine can use the wasted RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tool named Gavotte [Ramdisk](http://download.chip.eu/en/Gavotte-Ramdisk_5719636.html) to creates a virtual hard drive in the extra RAM memory and utilize unused RAM of your machine. Personally, I've found it very useful.

Answer (score 1):

No. It can't be accessed because it can't be mapped. You need to use a 64-bit host OS.